# Can anyone help me with a solution?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Write down the assumptions in a form of clauses and give a resolution proof that the proposition
                              $$\Big((p \rightarrow q) \land ( q \rightarrow r) \land p \Big) \rightarrow r$$ 
is a tautology.

Comment: do you mean "clauses" rather than "classes"?

Comment: yes classes....

Comment: lol..."clauses" or "classes"? Yes.

Comment: @amWhy: The original Q asks for "a resolution proof" of the formula, which seems to me a more specific request than showing it is a tautology (e.g. truth tables would probably not be accepted/allowed).

Comment: @amWhy: you have changed the question to make it match your answer. The original question was much more specific

Comment: @Rob: I rolled back to make you happy. I think in the long run, having a question with answers suggesting multiple proof methods and strategies would make a more valuable contribution to the site.

Comment: @Agnes: do not be put off by the votes to close ("off-topic" is a bit of a misnomer: it doesn't mean your subject is not wanted here). There are two things you ought to do. 1) make the title of your question more specific e.g.,, "Problem finding a resolution proof of a propositional tautology". 2) say  something about why are you having difficulty. E.g., say which part of the question is blocking you (finding the clauses or doing the resolution steps).

Comment: @amWhy: sure, your answer is useful, but I felt it was a bit of a rough welcome to a new user to see a vote to close (without any prior advice about MSE standards) and then have their question rewritten removing an important word.

Answer (score 2):

The negation of the goal has the following conjunctive normal form:
$$
\lnot(((p \rightarrow q) \land ( q \rightarrow r) \land p) \rightarrow r) \equiv 
(\lnot p \lor q)  \land (\lnot q \lor r) \land p \land \lnot r
$$
I.e., you have four clauses:
$$
\begin{array}{cl}
A:& \{\lnot p, q\}\\
B:& \{\lnot q, r\}\\
C:& \{p\}\\
D:& \{\lnot r\}
\end{array}
$$
$A$, $B$ and $C$ give the "assumptions in clause form" that your question is asking for.
The rest of the resolution proof goes like this:
$$
\begin{array}{clr}
E:& \{\lnot q\} & [B, D] \\
F:& \{\lnot p\} & [A, E] \\
G:& \{\mathsf{false}\} & [C, F]
\end{array}
$$
where the letters in square brackets tell you which earlier clauses to resolve to get the new clause. We have derived $\mathsf{false}$ from the negation of the goal by putting it into clause form and applying resolution inference steps. That constitutes a resolution proof of the goal.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have $p$ in the antecedent, and you have $p\rightarrow q$, and together, by modus ponens, you get $q$. Now, $q$, with the implication $q\rightarrow r$ give you $r$, again, using modus ponens.

So the conjunction in the antecedent (i.e. the three conjuncts in the antecedent) imply $r$.

Can you now use this to complete your assignment? Remember, the main connective here is an implication. The only way it can be false is if the antecedent is true but the consequent is false. By using the above rules of inference, you are guaranteed that if the antecedent (and hence each of the conjuncts) is true, so is the conclusion. I.e, the implication cannot be false.

Alternatively, you can proceed as follows (but you supply the justification for each line):$$\begin{align}\Big((p \rightarrow q) \land ( q \rightarrow r) \land p \Big) \rightarrow r &\equiv \lnot \big((p\rightarrow q) \land (q\rightarrow r) \land p\big) \lor r\\ \\ 
&\equiv \lnot\big((\lnot p \lor q) \land (\lnot q \lor r) \land p\big) \lor r\\ \\
&\equiv (\lnot(\lnot p \lor q) \lor \lnot(\lnot q \lor r) \lor \lnot p)\lor r\\ \\
&\equiv (p \land \lnot q) \lor (q \land \lnot r)\lor \lnot p \lor r\\ \\
&\equiv [(\lnot p \lor p) \land (\lnot p \lor \lnot q)] \lor [(r\lor q) \land (r \lor \lnot r)] \\ \\
&\equiv \lnot p \lor \lnot q \lor r \lor q\\ \\
&\equiv T\end{align}$$

Comment: Ok, thx very much i try do it :)

Comment: That still isn't a resolution proof. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)